# Compiler Error C2371 "redefinition of basic types" for unknown reason

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio community 2017. I have researched this issue and double checked that I am declare my value, and that I am not redefining, I have checked header guards. I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>

class FindLargestInt
{
    FindLargestInt(std::vector<int> &myVec)
    {
        int n = myVec[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++)
        {
            if (myVec[i] > n)
                n = myVec[i];
        }
        printf("%d", n);
    }


};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector{ 0, 3, 6, 8, 5 };

    FindLargestInt(myVector);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks anyone for your help.

```
Error   C2371   'myVector': redefinition; different basic types (line 29)

Error   C2512   'FindLargestInt': no appropriate default constructor available (line 29)
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error messages into your post?  You can copy from the output tab

Comment: @NathanOliver Oops yeah, edited.